# Need math for intuition

Tags: probability

Say, I have two sources of information, one is telling me that a person is located with high probability around street A. The probability is evenly distributed along that street so I cannot tell where on that street the person is located. The second source tells me that the person is highly likely to be located around street B also evenly distributed along the line. There is a junction of both streets. If I am looking for that person it is intuitive for me to start searching at the junction of A and B. However what happens there mathematically? If I want to extract for instance the probability of the person being in a circular region around the junction do I simply mix the distributions with equal weights? And if so why?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the position of the person. For every $C$, denote by $X\in C$ the event that $X$ is around $C$. 
One knows that $\Pr[X\in A]\geqslant p$ and $\Pr[X\in B]\geqslant q$.

This implies that $\Pr[X\in A\cap B]\geqslant p+q-1$. For example, if $\Pr[X\in A]\geqslant90\%$ and $\Pr[X\in B]\geqslant80\%$ then $\Pr[X\in A\cap B]\geqslant70\%$.

Comment: Why does $Pr[X\in A\cup B] \geq p+q-1$ hold? What if the intersection of the two sets is empty?

Comment: sorry confused cap and cup ^^